# JQuery, bootstrapValidator and ajaxForm(malsup) - No data posted

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, ajaxform

What I'm trying to implement a feature where the user clicks an icon to select a file. If the file is valid, it automatically starts to upload and shows a progress bar. Once done, it submits the data via AJAX and posts a response in a div.

So far, what I have managed to do is validate the filetype and begin upload with the progress bar. But when the upload completes, the url/action is called but no data is sent. I've tried doing a dump of POST, FILES, GET and REQUEST but they are all empty. Here is my code:

```
$('#attachmentForm').bootstrapValidator({
    container: 'tooltip',
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cross',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cycle'
    },
    fields: {
        attachment: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select a valid file.'
                },
                file: {
                    extension: 'jpg,jpeg,png,zip',
                    type: 'image/jpeg,image/png,application/zip',
                    maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20000,
                    message: 'The selected file is not valid.'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
.on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {    // detect presence of a valid file
    e.preventDefault();

    var progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
    var progressText = $('.selectfile').val();

    // Had to manually trigger a hidden button to submit form. If you have a better way to do this, I'm all ears.
    $('.attachmentForm-btn').trigger('click');   

    $('.upload-progress').slideDown(500);
    $('.cancelupload').slideDown(500);

    $('#attachmentForm').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            $('.cancelupload').click(xhr.abort)    // Need to include a cancel button. Will this work?
            var percentVal = '0%';
            progressBar.html('Uploading: '+ progressText.split('\\').pop());
            progressBar.width(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            progressBar.width(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            progressBar.width("100%");
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: posturl
    }); 
})
```

Here is the form

```
<form id="attachmentForm" name="attachmentForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group selectfile-wrap">
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="uploadAttachment" />
        <input type="file" class="form-control selectfile" name="attachment" />
        <button class="attachmentForm-btn" type="submit" style="display:none;"></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Check what is the result of your request using this method: afterSend: function(data) { (...) }.

Comment: Try also sending your request without jQuery. Use: <form action="url" method="post"> and check the results.

Comment: afterSend: function (data) { console.log(data); } - I tried this, but the console shows nothing. Also I've tried passing the url through the form and everything, but it just doesn't post. Would it matter if I have multiple forms on the page? They are separately validated and submitted, and only this one gets submitted using ajaxForm, other use plain $.ajax.

Comment: Actually, I didn't send the form WITHOUT JQuery, but I have other forms that use the same file and similar methods and they all work fine. I did however change .ajaxForm to .ajaxSubmit and tried. This would just take me to the action page and show an empty screen. Dumps came out empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved like so:

```
$('#attachmentForm').bootstrapValidator({
    container: 'tooltip',
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cross',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-cycle'
    },
    fields: {
        attachment: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Please select a valid file.'
                },
                file: {
                    extension: 'jpg,jpeg,png,zip',
                    type: 'image/jpeg,image/png,application/zip',
                    maxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 20000,
                    message: 'The selected file is not valid.'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
.on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
    $('#attachmentForm .uploadfilebtn').trigger('click');
})


$('#attachmentForm').ajaxForm({
    url: siteroot +'ajaxreq',
    type: 'post',
    data: {/* data here */},
    datatype: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        $('.upload-progress').slideDown(500);
        $('.cancelupload').slideDown(500);

        var ProgressText = $('.selectfile').val();

        $('.cancelupload').click(xhr.abort)
        var percentVal = '0%';
        $('.progress-bar').html('Uploading: '+ ProgressText.split('\\').pop());
        $('.progress-bar').width(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        $('.progress-bar').width(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        $('.progress-bar').width("100%");
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
});
```